# Creating a last run time stamp

Tags: java, applet

I have a small java project in which I would like to store the date and time the applet was last run on so I can display it to the user so they know when the applet was last run.

I cannot think of a method on storing the date and time because it cannot be a local file dun to the fact that this could be run on different machines.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not an expert in applets, but generally with browsers you can store things in cookies, in `localStorage` or by sending data to a server you control. It's hard to give more specifics than that, because this is a broad question. You should try to refine it a bit.

Comment: Ideally I would like to store, say a Date value and be able to recall when the program runs again

Comment: *"dun to the fact that this could be run on different machines."*  Well, if that means you expect to identify the **same user** accessing the applet from different machines, the most obvious way to implement that is to have the user log in.  That implies a server, and as suggested by @yshavit, the server could be used to display the user's last log-in/log-out times..  But really too broad for SO.  Also, ...

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).